# How parse channel entry fields content

Tags: stash, fields, parse

Is it possible parse ExpressionEngine tags *inside* the content of another tag?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}  
    {parseit {my_field}}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

my_field should contain any expression engine tag, even embed if it's possible.
Maybe it's possibile using stash, but I can't got how.

Thanks

EDIT, SECOND QUESTION, added allow_eecode:

```
<?php
    require_once "php.include/user_agent.inc.php";
?>
{embed="include/.head"}

{if segment_1 == ""}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="index" limit="1"} 
        {exp:replace_plus find="index.php|.php|/app" replace="{path='site_index'}||{path='site_index'}app/" multiple="yes"}
            {responsive_body_{language_code}}
        {/exp:replace_plus}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}

{exp:channel:entries channel="multi_version|responsive" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
    {if segment_1 != ""}
        {if no_results}
            {redirect="404"}
        {/if}
    {/if}
    {exp:replace_plus find="index.php|.php|/app" replace="{path='site_index'}||{path='site_index'}app/" multiple="yes"}
        {exp:switchee variable="{channel_name}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="responsive"}
                {exp:allow_eecode embed="yes"}
                    {responsive_body_{language_code}}
                {/exp:allow_eecode}
            {/case}
            {case value="multi_version"}
                <?php
                    if(userAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == "mobile"){
                ?>
                        {mobile_body_{language_code}}
                <?php
                    } else{
                ?>
                        {normal_body_{language_code}}
                <?
                    }
                ?>
            {/case}
        {/exp:switchee}
    {/exp:replace_plus}
{/exp:channel:entries}

</html>
```

that's the code, a bit complicate, but it work in other parts. the problem is in case responsive, where you can see {exp:allow_eecode embed="yes"}. in that field i have an embed like {embed="include/.newslist"}
and in my .newslist template I have:

```
test {language_code}

{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
    {news_title_{language_code}}
    test 2
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But I can see only "test it" in my responsive entry.

I have one news and it seems to be all fine. I can't got it.

SOLUTION:

adding dynamic="off" in embedded entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="off"}
    {news_title_{language_code}}
    test 2
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Allow EE Code](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}  
    {exp:allow_eecode}
        {my_field}
    {/exp:allow_eecode}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: looks awesome but just doesn't work! should i use some particular type of field or text formatting? I use textarea and "none" formatting and I continue to see unparsed ee tag.

Comment: yes, I use the same fieldtype. For example next page is going from entry- http://demo-ee.com/examples/view/qr-codes-generator. If you show you template, possible I can advice you something more.

Comment: if I use in my field some code like {language_code} or {entry_id} it is not parsed. I just added the parameter embed="yes" and I inserted an embed in my field: It works! But if insert in that embedde template some other code like just simple {exp:channel:entries} it does not work, so it's very usefull.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. i think that i'll change all and i'll use ajax for loading my dynamic content... it's even better.

Comment: ok. But just for reference -  {exp:channel:entries} must works also fine. On demo-ee I used it in example with maps. If you show you template code possible I can find issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require_once "php.include/user_agent.inc.php";
?>
{embed="include/.head"}

{if segment_1 == ""}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="index" limit="1"} 
        {exp:replace_plus find="index.php|.php|/app" replace="{path='site_index'}||{path='site_index'}app/" multiple="yes"}
            {responsive_body_{language_code}}
        {/exp:replace_plus}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}

{exp:channel:entries channel="multi_version|responsive" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
    {if segment_1 != ""}
        {if no_results}
            {redirect="404"}
        {/if}
    {/if}
    {exp:replace_plus find="index.php|.php|/app" replace="{path='site_index'}||{path='site_index'}app/" multiple="yes"}
        {exp:switchee variable="{channel_name}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="responsive"}
                {exp:allow_eecode embed="yes"}
                    {responsive_body_{language_code}}
                {/exp:allow_eecode}
            {/case}
            {case value="multi_version"}
                <?php
                    if(userAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == "mobile"){
                ?>
                        {mobile_body_{language_code}}
                <?php
                    } else{
                ?>
                        {normal_body_{language_code}}
                <?
                    }
                ?>
            {/case}
        {/exp:switchee}
    {/exp:replace_plus}
{/exp:channel:entries}

</html>
```

that's the code, a bit complicate, but it work in other parts. the problem is in case responsive, where you can see {exp:allow_eecode embed="yes"}. in that field i have an embed like {embed="include/.newslist"}
and in my .newslist template I have:

```
test {language_code}

{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
    {news_title_{language_code}}
    test 2
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But I can see only "test it" in my responsive entry.

I have one news and it seems to be all fine. I can't got it.

Comment: If i rename my embet removing dot, and i open in browser include/newslist I can see the list! All is fine.

Comment: did you try to add dynamic="off" into {exp:channel:entries channel="news"}?

Comment: Great! p.s. btw better to add this question (because it is not answer) into your question body and close this answer.